# how to remove detached object?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have planes and airports. They are related with ManyToMany relationship. I am trying to run jUnit test to check if everything is ok with database CRUD. Everything passed except remove methods. I am getting an error like: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Removing a detached instance..`

Both entities have Lists, for example Planes have Airports list and viceversa ( this is for MAnyToMany relationship).

Now, I am trying to delete it by doing this ( this method is in my PlanesDao):

```
public void remove(Planes plane) {
    entityManager.remove(plane);
}
```

But in this case, I also have to remove (somehow) a list of Airports which is related with plane. So I get lists of it and remove it like this:

*( before this, I make a select from database to take an Aiport and return it to Aiport objects)*

```
planesOne.getAirports().remove(aiportOne);
planesOne.getAirports().remove(aiportTwo);
planesTwo.getAirports().remove(aiportOne);
```

But error is the same... Help

Comment: Yes before you can do the removal through JPA, the entities have to be managed. If you don't know what that is I suggest you google "java JPA detached entity".

Comment: Ok, I got it. I forgot to add a transaction annotation to my test...huh, it works. !!! Because when it wasn't in transaction scope, it created detached objects, then I put all tests in transaction scope, all actions were started in the same scope, and this makes all objects attached. The result: it works fine!